Why Rust thinks that value is borrowed as mutable twice?
In the following code (Playground here)
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node {
    pub children: HashMap<char, Node>,
}

pub struct Trie {
    root: Node,
}

impl Trie {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Trie {
            root: Node { children: HashMap::new() }
        }
    }
        
    pub fn insert_v1_err(&mut self, word: String) {
        let mut current_node = &mut self.root;
        
        for char in word.chars() {
            let result = current_node.children.get_mut(&char);

            if result.is_some() {
                current_node = result.unwrap();
            }
        }
    }

    // current_node = result.unwrap(); is always executed
    pub fn insert_v2_ok(&mut self, word: String) {
        let mut current_node = &mut self.root;

        for char in word.chars() {
            let result = current_node.children.get_mut(&char);
            

            current_node = result.unwrap();
        }
    }
    // current_node = result.unwrap(); is never executed
    pub fn insert_v3_ok(&mut self, word: String) {
        let mut current_node = &mut self.root;

        for char in word.chars() {
            let result = current_node.children.get_mut(&char);

            println!("{:}", result.is_some());
        }
    }
}


I have the error:
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `current_node.children` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:23:26
   |
23 |             let result = current_node.children.get_mut(&char);
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                          |
   |                          `current_node.children` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
   |                          first borrow used here, in later iteration of loop


Why Rust compiler thinks that the value is borrowed as mutable twice in insert_v1_err method? Taking into account that if we split the condition in two separate methods insert_v2_ok and insert_v3_ok it does work.
In my understanding, the result variable is invalidated at the end of each iteration, so the muttable borrow never occures twice. Could you explain the logic of the compiler?

It's a limitation of the current borrow checker. You can't reuse result, replace it with the full current_node.children.get_mut(&char) inside the if.
